# Crazy Ant Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors

A crazy ant is standing on the origin.

It starts by walking 1 unit in the positive x axis direction and then turns 60 degrees counterclockwise and walks 1/2 units in that direction.

The ant then turns another 60 degrees and walks 1/3 units in that direction.

The ant keeps doing this endlessly.

Find the final position of the ant.

My Approach -

I tried solving by polar coordinates but couldn't reach a definite answer . I think I might be approaching the problem wrongly. Hints to proceed will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the ant can be calculated as a sum of the displacement vectors at each step (walk + turn):
$$
\mathbf{r} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\mathbf{r}_n,
$$
where every displacement vector is obtained as
$$
\mathbf{r}_n=\frac{1}{n}\hat{R}^{n-1}\mathbf{r}_1,
$$
where $\hat{R}$ is the rotation matrix by $60^\circ$.

It remains to write down the rotation matrix and to sum the series.